# What should I do if C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe got infected?

Tags: malware, windows, antimalware, rootkits

The original `svchost.exe` file in my Windows XP was changed with a malicious copy, I think this is easy to do on Windows XP.

How am I supposed to return it to the clean original without crashing the system? Should I just install a new OS?

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/protect/forum/protect_other-protect_scanning/svchostexe-process-got-infected/9720c251-1bd4-4997-ad56-a4ab98122b9b?auth=1

Comment: @Limit Unfortunately, I don't have the Windows XP CD currently. SFC requires it, is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Fortunately this is not a malware support forum. Your question is off-topic here. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, You could connect your HDD to another non infected computer and replace the svhost.exe file from there (You could find this in the Windows XP installation disk). And scan the HDD for malware. It will work.

Note: If you don't have the WinXP installation disk, you could download the svhost.exe for the WindowsXP [here](http://originaldll.com/file/svchost.exe/40216.html). But you have to trust that website.